# ¿Cómo agregar fechas pre-determinadas a un gráfico de una serie de tiempo?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Tengo un gráfico de la siguiente forma:
[image: gráfico serie de tiempo]
El código que estoy utilizando es:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(9,2))
plt.plot(df['var1'], 'k')
plt.xlabel('Date')
```

Mi data es diaria y las fechas están en el índice, en la forma: "2001-01-01 00:00:00". Creo que es formato timestamp.
Necesito que el gráfico señale en el ejeX el inicio de cada año, y que señale solo el año. Además necesito otro gráfico en donde se señale cada inicio de mes, junto a su año respectivo. Básicamente, igual al actual, pero en lugar de 2002, 2004, 2006... que sea 2001, 2002, 2003... Y el otro algo como: 2001-Jan, 2001,-Feb...

En base a ejemplos de la web, he estado intentando esto, sin éxito:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df['var1'])

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(years)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(years_fmt)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(months)

datemin = np.datetime64(df.index[0], 'Y')
datemax = np.datetime64(df.index[-1], 'Y') + np.timedelta64(1, 'Y')
ax.set_xlim(datemin, datemax)

ax.format_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
ax.format_ydata = lambda x: '$%1.2f' % x  # format the price.
ax.grid(True)

fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo en principio usando `axis.xaxis.set_major_locator()` y 
`ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter()` junto a `matplotlib.dates.mdates` para especificar los intervalos.

Por años:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


start = pd.Timestamp(2016, 1, 1, 12)
end = pd.Timestamp(2018, 12, 31, 12, 0, 0)
times = pd.date_range(freq='15d', start=start, end=end)
data = np.random.randint(400, 800, times.shape)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=["var1"], index=times)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 2))
ax.plot(df['var1'], 'k')
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y')) 
fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)

plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Para hacerlo por meses:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates



start = pd.Timestamp(2016, 1, 1, 12)
end = pd.Timestamp(2018, 12, 31, 12, 0, 0)
times = pd.date_range(freq='15d', start=start, end=end)
data = np.random.randint(400, 800, times.shape)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=["var1"], index=times)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 2))
ax.plot(df['var1'], 'k')
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%b')) 
fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)

plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ten en cuenta que si tienes muchos años, al tener 12 etiquetas por año, no cogerán físicamente en el eje y se terminarán solapando.